# Spring 4 security rule definition

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-security

I had updated spring security from 3x to `4.0.1.RELEASE`. Then I finally had the change to fully remove old XML, and replace it with pure java config. But my security isn't working properly.

Problem:

- my default login page does not authorize, under POST /login.htm I have 404.
- my main app can run as unauthorized
- because I have 404 on login POST, I am not entering UserDetailsService
- all beans are provided into this configuration, I have no context start problems

My configuration file:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.dal.dao.security", "com.services.security"})
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    LocalUserDao userDao;

    @Autowired
    UserRoleMapper roleMapper;

    @Autowired
    StandardPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    private UserDetailsService methodSecurityService() throws Exception {
        return new UserDetailsServiceImpl(userDao, roleMapper);
    }

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(methodSecurityService()).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/*")
                .authenticated()

                .and()

                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login.htm").failureUrl("/login.htm?error")
                .usernameParameter("username")
                .passwordParameter("password")
                .and().logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/index.htm")
                .and().csrf()
                .and().exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/403");
    }

}
```

Could anyone help me with this? I have already watched few no-xml configuration, but they don't seem to be working on my example.

Source of my code can be found [here](http://www.mkyong.com/spring-security/spring-security-hibernate-annotation-example/).

Comment: Have you tried `.loginPage("/login").failureUrl("/login?error")`?  I'm thinking that your controller may be looking for that.

Comment: Also, you can enable debug logging on `org.spring.web.context` and `org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractUrlHandlerMapping` and `org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping` to see what Spring is really doing

Comment: 2 things directly apparent, Your `/*` for all access should be `/**` it is an ant based match and `/*` is only single level deep. You haven't' added an access rule for the login page, this can be done by adding `permitAll` to the `formLogin` configuration, the same applies to the logout handling and exception handling.

Comment: @Beri, have you tried the fix i suggested to see whether it will work?

Comment: Yes I have tried, but with no results. Now I will start looking for a working demo, that I could rewrite. My xml version also does not work after migrating to spring 4.01, so the problem is not connected with annotation driven approach only.

Answer (score 1):

I think the fix is simple (i hope) you didn't advise that anyone can access your login form:

```
http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/*")
                .authenticated()

                .and()

                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login.htm").failureUrl("/login.htm?error")
                .usernameParameter("username")
                .passwordParameter("password")

                .permitAll()   // ADD THIS LINE

                .and().logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/index.htm")
                .and().csrf()
                .and().exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/403");
```

Essentially you are redirecting users to login page without enabling unauthenticated access to it. Basically you are asking them to authenticate to view the authentication form :).

From Spring Security:

> Granting access to the formLogin() URLs is not done by default since
>   Spring Security needs to make certain assumptions about what is
>   allowed and what is not. To be secure, it is best to ensure granting
>   access to resources is explicit.